# Should we use multiply learning rate by x or $\sqrt(x)$ when batch size is multiplied by x?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, batch-normalization

According to this paper, One weird trick for parallelizing convolutional neural networks 
(https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5997), it is suggested that we multiply learning rate by $\sqrt(x)$, but according to  Accurate, Large Minibatch SGD: Training ImageNet in 1 Hour (https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02677), it is suggested that we do linear scaling. It seems that the first paper has more theoretical underpinnings to it, but I am confused as to which approach I should take in practice. So, should we use multiply learning rate by x or $\sqrt(x)$ when batch size is multiplied by x when training a convolutional neural network?